# How to archive several files in one ZIP file?

Tags: c#, uwp, zip

I am trying to archive the content of a folder into a zip file.. the content are mostly large images. I am trying to do this using this code:

```
var folderPicker =
      new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation =
      Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
if (folder != null)
  {
    StorageFile zipFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(ThemeName.Text + ".zip",
        Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
    Stream themeZipFile = await zipFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
    ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(themeZipFile);
    StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFolder temp = await localFolder.GetFolderAsync("Temp");
    var files = await temp.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (var item in files)
      {
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(item.Path, item.Name);
      }
   }
```

However, when executed, I receive an error:

> IOException: Cannot seek to an absolute stream position that is negative.

Now when I try this code:

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
StorageFolder folder = 
    await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
if (folder != null)
  {
    StorageFile zipFile =
        await folder.CreateFileAsync(ThemeName.Text + ".zip", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
    await Task.Run(() => ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(localFolder.Path, zipFile.Path));
  }
```

I get that access is denied to whatever folder I pick !
How can I get around this to combine several larger files into one archive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to archive several files in one ZIP file?

`CreateFromDirectory` method will create zip file with second `destinationArchiveFileName`
 paramater. So you need not create zip file in advance. You could use the follwing code to zip your folder directly.

```
if (ZipFolder != null)
{
    // Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder (including other sub-folder contents)
    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", ZipFolder);
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, $"{ZipFolder.Path}\\{Guid.NewGuid()}.zip");
            Debug.WriteLine("folder zipped");
        }
        catch (Exception w)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(w);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: This worked great ! thank you !! .. When using `Guid.NewGuid()` as a name it works, but when I replace it with the folder name it does not .. any idea how to catch the file to rename it ?

Comment: I have passed  `$"{ZipFolder.Path}\\{ZipFolder.Name}.zip"` parameter, it also works.

Answer (score 1):

Using this method, you are able to create a ZIP file starting from a source directory.
Here some Docs by Microsoft: [ZIPFile.CreateFromDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.createfromdirectory?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Compression_ZipFile_CreateFromDirectory_System_String_System_String_System_IO_Compression_CompressionLevel_System_Boolean_)

You can find the mentioned class and method in this namespace: System.IO.Compression

Answer (score 1):

If creating a temp folder to archive the whole folder is a solution for you try this:

```
using System.IO.Compression;

var files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(string PATH, ".jpeg", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

 foreach (var file in files)
   {
   File.Copy(file, tempPath + @"\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
   }

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(tempPath, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);

Directory.Delete(tempPath, true); //delete tempfolder after compress commplete
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. correct me if I am wrong, but the `Directory.EnumerateFiles` class is to filter the content of a file.
In the app I am working on the temp folder is used to collect the files to be archived (jpeg, jpg, png and configuration text files, so everything in temp must be compressed).
when `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory`  in its own class I get an empty zip file. I thought maybe it requires a stream to make it work !

Comment: I don't exactly understand your point. You can filter for more files, you can easily add .png or other endings to it.